# jquery autocomplete not working, nothing appears when typing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this input text that is being created via `$.each`:

```
$.each(results, function (key, value) {

                        if (typeof value.baseOrSchedStartList[i] != 'undefined') {
                            html += "<td><input type='text' name='" + key + "-" + taskArray[i] + "' id='vendorDropdown' class='vendorDropdown' value='" + value.baseOrSchedStartList[i].split(' ')[0] + "' /></td>";
                        } else {
                            html += "<td>&nbsp;</td>"
                        }

                    });
```

and I am trying to apply autocomplete to it:

```
var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];

    $("#vendorDropdown").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
    });
```

But when I start typing nothing happens. i get no errors in my console. I have jquery UI installed, but nothing is happening.

Comment: You are creating the element `vendorDropdown` dynamically, but you aren't binding to it dyamically. Your current `vendorDropdown.autocomplete();` is checking for elements that are loaded at the time of the DOM being prepared. Your `html` string concatenator is firing `after` the DOM is prepared. **tl;dr** run your autocomplete code after you've created the element with javascript.

Comment: all my jquery is inside a document.ready code.

Comment: In your "each" statement, where does the array index " i " get it's value? That part of the code works as you expect?

Answer (score 1):

Try run autocomplete in this way:

```
$('#tags').on('keyup',function(){
  $(this).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
```